# CurrentVersion value in registry for each windows operating system

Tags: windows, registry, nsis

I want to know `CurrentVersion` value for each operating system at

```
HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion"
```

For example: I have windows 7 professional installed on my machine and `CurrentVersion` value is `6.1`.

Can any one list it down for all windows operating systems since Windows 98?

Comment: That's for win2k and above: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724832(v=vs.85).aspx. Are you really going to support win98?

Comment: thanks a lot. Its fine if I dont get it for windows 98.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

These are the required versions of windows operating systems:

```
Operating system              Version number
----------------------------  --------------
Windows 10                      10.0
Windows Server 2019             10.0
Windows Server 2016             10.0
Windows 8.1                     6.3
Windows Server 2012 R2          6.3
Windows 8                       6.2
Windows Server 2012             6.2
Windows 7                       6.1
Windows Server 2008 R2          6.1
Windows Server 2008             6.0
Windows Vista                   6.0
Windows Server 2003 R2          5.2
Windows Server 2003             5.2
Windows XP 64-Bit Edition       5.2
Windows XP                      5.1
Windows 2000                    5.0
Windows ME                      4.90
Windows 98                      4.10
```

If you want to know it by reading it from registry, you need to check the new `CurrentMajor/MinorVersionNumber` keys as well. The new values `CurrentMajorVersionNumber` (which is 10) and `CurrentMinorVersionNumber` (which is 0) under Windows 10. Those [2 keys are new in Windows 10 to detect Windows Version from Registry](https://github.com/project-jedi/jcl/pull/18/files#diff-ea48926a7d3868ba7cb1597fc48cff54R3868).

Comment: Do note, though, that the registry key in question will contain "6.3" for Windows 10. You need to check the new "CurrentMajor/MinorVersionNumber" keys as well: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31072543/87698

Comment: Does anybody know the CurrentMajor/MinorVersionNumber pair for the Windows 10 november update?

Comment: @Sebastian Kind of late, but the version number is always 10.0 for Windows 10. Major updates are identified by their [version number](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/windows-10/release-information) which you can find in the "ReleaseId" value: The "November update" is release 1511.

Comment: @Max Truxa releaseid no longer works for 21h1, instead displayversion is now used. which doesn't exist for older versions

Comment: @az1d Well that sucks. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `WinVer.nsh` to check the Windows version...

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the following key for more specific string details about the OS

Reg query "\hostname\HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /v ProductName

I've found to be present for Windows XP and aboeve....

Answer (score 1):

updatable list located at MSDN : 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724832.aspx

for now (March 2015) :

```
Operating system              Version number
----------------------------  --------------
Windows 10 Tech.Preview       10.0
Windows Server Techn.Preview  10.0
Windows 8.1                    6.3
Windows Server 2012 R2         6.3
Windows 8                      6.2
Windows Server 2012            6.2
Windows 7                      6.1
Windows Server 2008 R2         6.1
Windows Server 2008            6.0
Windows Vista                  6.0
Windows Server 2003 R2         5.2
Windows Server 2003            5.2
Windows XP 64-Bit Edition      5.2
Windows XP                     5.1
Windows 2000                   5.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Just checked Windows 10 Pro and it is version 6.3

Comment: this is wrong. Windows 8.1 is internally 6.3. Windows 10 is 10.0 and early Preview builds were 6.4.

Comment: Win 10+ has a new key for tracking the version. You should use `Reg Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /v CurrentMajorVersionNumber`and `Reg Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /v CurrentMinorVersionNumber`.