# Check windows version from registry c#

Tags: c#

I have a problem,
How can I check the windows version from the registry in c#?

(Windows xp to windows 8.1)

Comment: *Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results*

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the "friendly" OS Version Name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/577634/how-to-get-the-friendly-os-version-name)

Comment: My question, Why do you check registry for version? can't you get it from `Environment` class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Environment.OSVersion` as others stated is right way to go.

However, in case someone want to get it through registry, this can be used -

```
using (Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = 
       Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine
               .OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion"))
{
    var osVersion = key.GetValue("CurrentVersion");
}
```

Registry for version is `HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion"`.

Also, corresponding mapping with actual OS from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14648796/currentversion-value-in-registry-for-each-windows-operating-system) -

```
Operating system        Version number
-----------------       --------------
Windows 8                   6.2
Windows Server 2012         6.2
Windows 7                   6.1
Windows Server 2008 R2      6.1
Windows Server 2008         6.0
Windows Vista               6.0
Windows Server 2003 R2      5.2
Windows Server 2003         5.2
Windows XP 64-Bit Edition   5.2
Windows XP                  5.1
Windows 2000                5.0
```

Comment: Note that, and I've seen this...WindowsNT may actually have a space in it...so the key could be "Windows NT".

Comment: How to output `osVersion` to a MessageBox ?!

Comment: I am using windows 10 and get `6.2`

Comment: @Black - For windows 10 you need to check CurrentMajorVersionNumber and CurrentMinoVersionNumber as well. Refer to this for more details - https://stackoverflow.com/a/31143093/632337

Comment: System.Environment.OSVersion will return the compatibility mode instead of actual OS Version unless you are using .Net Framework 4.7+

Answer (score 7):

`Environment.OSVersion` can give you that!

Read the MSDN documentation for [Environment class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.aspx) to see all of the other things you can get from this class.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to read the registry; [System.Environment.OSVersion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.osversion.aspx) gives you this information.

Comment: In case of Win8.1 the version is 6.3.*

Comment: System.Environment.OSVersion will return the compatibility mode instead of actual OS Version unless you are using .Net Framework 4.7+