# Reliable way to get Windows Version from registry

Tags: windows, registry, nsis, windows-10, version-detection

I'm checking the windows version in an installer (made with NSIS) by checking the following registry key:

```
HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" "CurrentVersion"
```

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14702072/549195) and [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724832(v=vs.85).aspx) from MSDN, the currentVersion number for Windows 10 should be 10.0.

I just installed the Windows 10 Pro Insider Preview and the version number given in the registry is still 6.3, instead of 10.10 as it should.

Is there another reliable way in registry to detect Windows 10?

Comment: there is a new value CurrentMajorVersionNumber which is 10 and CurrentMinorVersionNumber which is 0 in my Win10 VM.

Comment: Why is reading it from the registry a requirement?

Comment: Thanks @magicandre1981. This is what I needed. I checked if these keys exist and the value of these keys.

Comment: ok, I posted it as answer.

Comment: Or use the version plugin: http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Version_plug-in

Comment: @Anders, reading the registry is often the only mechanism that's reliable from *outside* the running OS.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Instead of reading the value `CurrentVersion`, read the new values `CurrentMajorVersionNumber` (which is 10) and `CurrentMinorVersionNumber` (which is 0) under Windows 10. Those [2 keys are new in Windows 10 to detect Windows Version from Registry](https://github.com/project-jedi/jcl/pull/18/files#diff-ea48926a7d3868ba7cb1597fc48cff54R3868).

Answer (score 3):

There's also a human-readable string in the registry called "ProductName"

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
private string getOSInfo()
{
   string registry_key = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion";
   var key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(registry_key);
   var value = key.GetValue("ProductName");
   return value.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProductName
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ReleaseId
```

Which gives me 10 and 1709.

Comment: At least for Win10 Enterprise, the ProductName is "Windows 10 Enterprise"...

Answer (score 2):

See Peter Bright's article at https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2014/11/why-windows-10-isnt-version-6-any-more-and-why-it-will-probably-work/ for more insight on why you see the answers you do. As you already saw from @magicandre1981, the `CurrentMajorVersionNumber` key will give you the "10" you want. You can get 10.0 from `System.Environment.OSVersion` **if** the application manifest *explicitly* designates your app for Windows 10, as stated in the referenced article. Without it, `Environment.OSVersion` will give you 6.2.9200, which is the same as Windows 8. So, your Windows 10 version is 10.0, 6.3, or 6.2, depending on how you ask the question.